# Project files are not showing after updating to Android Studio to 3.3

Tags: android-studio, updates

On updating Android Studio to version 3.3, the previously opened projects have some issues.

In the project structure activity, gradle and Xml files are missing; only iml files are present.

The project structure is as shown here:

[image: project structure]

Comment: Try to close project, remove it in "recent projects list" and open again.

Comment: it is not working any other suggestion

Comment: no gradle is set or module is not getting added any help

Comment: Ensure the files are actually present in the project. Also, try checking in "Android" view rather than "Project" view by clicking the button on top of the sidebar

Comment: Android view is not present